# iOS Box API V2- GetUpdates Function

Tags: ios, box-api

I want to use the GetUpdates API function with iOS Box sdk V2. I have seen such a method in Box Api v1 and also in the Box SDK I have an in built class called **BoxUpdateOperation** that does the same for me. How to do this with API v2 or the box sdk v2.

V1 API function :http://developers.box.net/w/page/22926051/ApiFunction_get_updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is the /events API.  I'm not sure if the iOS sdk has built methods to connect to that endpoint yet.  You could definitely implement it and submit it as a pull request.